# Which options exist for exporting music used on the timeline?

Tags: premiere, final-cut-pro-x, avid

I'm trying to get an overview of which options I have to get a list of audible music used on a Premiere Pro, Avid Media Compoaer and Final Cut Pro timeline. I mention audible, because I would not be interested in music on the timeline which is e.g. muted - and thus not audible.

I would be interested in knowing e.g. the filename, start and stop positions to build a summary of the music used - and audible - on a timeline.

Such a list could simply be the name of files (containing the music) used on the timeline.

I know these applications can extract EDL lists, but I am uncertain how precise these are. Is this the best I can get in terms of timeline summaries, or do I have other options?

I am not interested in 3rd party applications, but only functionality provided by the applications themselves.

What is the best way to extract a summary of e.g. filenames, start and stop positions - and how can i make sure that these extracts only include audible music?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge FCPX does not have anything built in for this. You would need 3rd party. 
If you willing to use 3rd party my best bet would be [Producer’s Best Friend](http://intelligentassistance.com/producer-s-best-friend.html)